# I am facing difficulties in backing up a database in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, backup, ssms, sql-server-2019

[image]When I try to backup a database, it is showing this message :

> to accomplish this action set property devices.
> (microsoft.sqlserver.smoextended)

I cannot able to select the file location to backup as you can see in the picture that OK button is not enabled.

I tried to change the permission of folders, but the permissions are not changing.

Note: I am using MS SQL Server -2022- 2019

Comment: @Ronaldo yes I am using the wizard and I attached the screenshot along with it

Comment: What version of SSMS?

Comment: 18.11.1 developer edition @J.D.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2022, you are probably under NDA for an unreleased product and have direct access to people who can answer your questions. Your screenshot indicates that you're probably using SQL Server 2019.

Comment: @alroc no I am using SQL Server 2022 developer edition

Comment: Could you, please, run `SELECT @@version` and add the result to the question? Could you try to execute the backup using T-SQL? Try running `BACKUP DATABASE WideWorldImporters
TO DISK = 'C:\your_path\WideWorldImporters.bak';`

Comment: @Ronaldo oh sorry it is version 2019, I tried with the script and it is showing the following error message:                                                                                           
        Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\WideWorldImporters-Full.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: *"I tried to change the permission of folders, but the permissions are not changing."* what does that mean, what did you do? You need to give permissions to the SQL Server service account

Answer (score 2):

I see you are using SQL 2019, not SQL 2022. I can see this from both object explorer and also from the backup path. The number 15 is for SQL 2019. SQL 2022 is still in private preview and not yet publicly available.

I've included a screenshot of how to take a backup using the wizard in SSMS. The OK button is disabled until you enter a name for the backup file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're having issues with permissions, just pick a different folder where SQL server does have access.